# [Openerp]How to make SQL Query with another database user from python code?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, openerp-7

I need to make SQL Query in Openerp with another user than postgres from python code that has only SELECT privileges. Is there a way that cursor(cr) receives connection string?

Comment: Why negative? It would be nice if you try to answer the question first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an easy solution for this. As OpenERP uses psycopg as postgres database cursor I have explicitly made an psycopg object with parameters that I need:

```
conn = psycopg1.connect(database=cr.dbname,  user=dbuser,  password=dbpass)
cur = conn.cursor()
```

Be careful, if you want to use dictfetchall you need to import psycopg1:

```
from psycopg2 import psycopg1

cur.execute(sql)
res = cur.dictfetchall()
```